# How to add units in Mathematical style (like Latex) to a Plotly graph without eroding the rest of the label?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I want to make a graph that has something on the y-axis, and something on the x-axis where the x axis is given in metres squared. I've tried using Latex dollar signs to put it in 'equation mode' but this gets rid of the text before it.

Code snippet:

```
figure = go.Figure(
        layout=go.Layout(
            xaxis_title="Area ($m^2$)",
            yaxis_title="Value ($m/s$)"
        ))
```

When I run the above the 'Area' part of the x-axis title doesn't appear, only the m^2 units. How do I simultaneously get the title and the units in mathematical style to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only works if the whole label is surrounded by `$` signs, thus the following works.

```py
figure = go.Figure(
        layout=go.Layout(
            xaxis_title=r"$\text{Area }(m^2)$",
            yaxis_title=r"$\text{Value }(m/s)$"
        ))
```

Notice that we write `r"$\text{...`, or otherwise we need to escape the backslash, e.g. `"$\\text{..."`.